# How to get collectstatic to collect the static files of an external App

Tags: django, static, collectstatic

I'm working on a project that requires an external fileupload package, which is a separate project. 'collectstatic' does not include the static files of that external package.
Do I need to change the external package or can I use the settings.py of my project to include the static files?
It works if I do:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('my_app/static')),
    str(APPS_DIR.path('../other_app/fileupload/static'))
)
```

But this will not work on the deployment server.

Comment: can you add folder tree

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your app in INSTALLED_APPS; then collectstatic will include its files automatically.